# discriminative union not working in react.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
export type Topic = {
  type: "topic";
  id: number;
  name: string;
  info_image: string;
  video?: string;
  caption_file_url?: string;
  pdf?: string;
  image?: string;
  content?: string;
  description?: string;
};

export interface Assessment {
  type: "assesment";
  id: number;
  name: string;
  pre_assesment: boolean;
  order: number;
  max_marks: number;
  min_marks_to_qualify: number;
  course: number;
  topic: number;
  parent: number;
  question: Question[];
}


type TopicProp = {
  topic?: Assessment | TopicType;
};


const Topic = ({ topic }: TopicProp) => {
  if (topic?.type === "topic") {
    return (
      <div>
       <h1>TOPIC</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
     <div>
        <h1>Assesment</h1>
    </div>
   )
};
```

but its rendering noting why like this happening and it seems react.js ignoring the code.
how to solve it and why its happening like this.
i actually trying to narrow the typing with dicrimative union with typescript.

sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-eesic4

Comment: Could you either provide a [mre] suitable for demonstrating your issue in a standalone IDE, or provide a link to a web IDE project that demonstrates your issue? If not, it'll be quite difficult to diagnose your issue remotely.

Comment: I added sandbox link please check it out tqs

Comment: From that link it seems you are not passing a `type` property in the props for `Topic` so it falls off the bottom of the implementation of `Topic`.  There are a number of other errors in that code that you don't seem to be asking about, so it's not really a [mre]. What's `TopicType`? What's `Question`? What type does `Topic` return?

Comment: If I fix those, like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-ct8zql?file=/src/App.tsx), then you get the error at `<Topic topic=...>` saying `Property 'type' is missing`.  So my suggestion is that you fix all your TypeScript errors before asking about why it isn't working, or at least mention the errors in your question directly.  So what should we do here?  Should I write up an answer or do you want to remove the question?